# How to reinit AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayeritem

I am initializing AVPlayerItem with "initWithUrl:" method.

Issue is that when initialization is interrupted (e.g. connection is lost)

Let's say we have following:

```
self.avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithUrl:url];
```

1.
What should be done? What happens to instance of avPlayerItem when connection is lost meanwhile?
Is there some protocol to implement in order to identify if initialization was successful or not?

2.
What I have noticed is that once initialization is interrupted then next "successful" initialization of avPlayerItem doesn't have tracks at all (they are present when no interruption is done before)
To initialize avPlayerItem with tracks again from the source user needs to close and open the app again.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with code that relies on internet connection you have to make sure there are failsafes that kick in when something goes wrong, because at some point it will.

> What should be done?

1) Perform all code that relies on internet connection on a background thread. You don't want to block up the UI.

2) If possible verify the downloaded file before using.

There are different ways of going about this but off the top of my head I think I would use `NSURLConnection` or similar API to download the file into a temp folder. ON A BACKGROUND THREAD.

When downloaded I would initialise an `AVAsset` using the temp URL. `AVAsset` has some nice properties like `playable` that will help you check that the file downloaded OK. (`NSURLConnectionDelegate` also has a method that notifies if there was an error downloading.)

If you've got this far then you can create an `AVPlayerItem` with your `AVAsset` and away you go. Remember to wipe the contents of your temp folder at some point if you're not hanging on to the downloaded content.

Remember that you want to play your file on the main thread but all other loading and checking is probably best done on a background thread; you definitely want to use `NSURLConnection` from a background thread.

Comment: thanks for great answer. I am using GCD to download file. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ ... ` I tried to use `[AVURLAsset initWithUrl:options:]` and I tried to initialise AVPlayerItem with this asset. Item is initialised but still doesn't have tracks. Probably I am not cleaning instance properly. But I see in code that all observers are removed and avplayeritem (also avplayer.currentitem etc.) are set to nil when something goes wrong..)

Comment: `AVAsset` has a property named `tracks` so you can get track info pre playing. So if you're expecting 2 tracks and you get 1 you know something went wrong. I expect that there is an error somewhere in the init process and that's why you have issues. Either that or you downloaded a corrupted file.

Comment: I am expecting one track and I get 0. File is fine because when I run the app and try to get the same file again then everything works fine. I have problem only when the initWithUrl is interrupted with connection loss. Then every time after interruption I get 0 tracks even when accesing other files. As I say. When connection is not lost during init then everything works just fine, also when accessing other files later on.

Comment: OK well this is most likely because it is trying to load a half loaded file. If you use `NSURLConnection` you can catch that interruption and delete the downloaded file and re-download. If you don't want to use `NSURLConnection` you could just assume that if you have 0 tracks you need to delete the file and re-download. You can gracefully handle this by showing an alert to the user of whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Store the AVPlayerItem in an NSPurgeableData object first, and play from that; store the data object in an NSCache object to automatically evict the object from memory after it has played, or when the connection is dropped, and the former AVPlayerItem is replaced by a new one (all of these things you should be doing anyway, regardless of the particular problem you describe). Here's some code to get you started:

```
void (^cachePlayerItem)(AVPlayerItem *, NSCache *, NSString *) = ^(AVPlayerItem *playerItem, NSCache *cache, NSString *key) {
    NSURL *fileURL = [(AVURLAsset *)playerItem.asset URL];
    NSPurgeableData *data = [NSPurgeableData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    [data beginContentAccess];
    [cache setObject:data forKey:key];
    [data endContentAccess];
    [data discardContentIfPossible];
};
```

Put this block anywhere in an implementation file, defining it in the header file with:

```
typedef void (^cachePlayerItemBlock)(AVPlayerItem *, NSCache *, NSString *);
```

Call it within a method with:

```
cachePlayerItem(playerItem, playerItems, phAsset.localIdentifier);
```

Whereas, playerItem is the AVPlayerItem, playerItems is the NSCache cache, and, depending on what kind of asset from which you are acquiring the AVPlayerItem, an identifier of some kind unique to it (or, in the example above, its associated asset).

By the way, I set up my caches in AppDelegate accordingly:

```
- (NSCache *)thumbnailCache {
    __block NSCache *t = self->_thumbnailCache;
    if (!t) {
        t = [[NSCache alloc] init];
        [t setName:@"Thumbnail Cache"];
        [t setEvictsObjectsWithDiscardedContent:TRUE];
        [t setCountLimit:self.assetsFetchResults.count];
        self->_thumbnailCache = t;
    }
    return t;
}
```

This ensures not only global access to, but also one instance of, the cache, which is particularly important when caching AVPlayerItems, as they can be large in size.

To create a globally accessible cache in AppDelegate, add these to your header and implementation files, respectively:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
```

...and:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

To reference the cache in other class files, import the AppDelegate header file, and, if desired, create a shortcut to the AppDelegate's sharedApplication method:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define AppDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

Insodoing, the cache can be referenced by...:

```
AppDelegate.thumbnailCache
```

...instead of:

```
AppDelegate.sharedAppDelegate.thumbnailCache
```